# C problem with saving structure to text file and downloading it back to stdout

Tags: c

Hey I have a problem with my code project where I try to create a project that keeps up wit Olympic medals. I have a problem of creating a text file that contains the structure and is named by user. I also have a problem to download the structure.

PROBLEM: I have a problem to make a text file named by user that contains the structure and then download it back to stdout. I don't know how to fix my functions to do this correctly. Now my function save_file can't even produce the file.

Example if the input:

A Canada

A USA

M USA 2 1 1

M Canada 0 0 1

M USA 1 3 1

M USA -1 0 0

L

W medals

Q

I have defined my structure this way:

```
typedef struct Olympia
    {
        char* country;
        int gold;
        int silver;
        int bronze;
    }Olympia;
```

Then I have a function that adds country

```
int add_country(struct Olympia* data, char* str, int i)
{
    if (str[0] == '\0') //checking that input is correct
    {
        printf("Error! Try again!\n");
    }

    else
    {
        data[i].country = malloc(strlen(str) + 2);  //allocating memory for country name
        strcpy(data[i].country, str);   //adding country to database
        data[i].gold = 0;   //setting medals to zero
        data[i].silver = 0;
        data[i].bronze = 0;
        i++;
    }
    return i;
}
```

Next I add medals to the each country

```
int update_medals(struct Olympia* data, char* str, int add_gold, int add_silver, int add_bronze, int i)
{
    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;

    if (str[0] == '\0') //checking that input is correct
    {
        printf("Error! Try again!");
    }

    else
    {
        while (a < i)
        {
            if (strcmp(data[a].country, str) == 0)  //adding medals to right country
            {
                data[a].gold = data[a].gold + add_gold;
                data[a].silver = data[a].silver + add_silver;
                data[a].bronze = data[a].bronze + add_bronze;
                b++;
            }
            a++;
        }

        if (b == 0) //and if the country didn't participate to the olympics
        {
            printf("This country isn't in the Olympics! Try Again!\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Next there is print function

```
int print_data(struct Olympia* data, int i)
{
    for (int a = 0; a < i; a++)
    {
        printf("%s %d %d %d\n", data[a].country, data[a].gold, data[a].silver, data[a].bronze);
    }
}
```

And then there are the two function that doesn't work. What should I do?

```
Olympia *save_file(Olympia* data, const char* filename, int i)
{
    if (strlen(filename) > 100)
    {
        printf("Filename is too long: Maxium lenght for filename is 100 characters");
        return data;
    }

    char name[100];
    int ret = sscanf(filename, "W %s", name);
    if (ret != 1)
    {
        printf("Error! Try again!");
        return data;
    }


    FILE* file = fopen(name, "w");
    if (!file)
    {
        printf("Error saving file! Try again");
        return data;
    }

    int a = 0;
    while (data[a].country[0] != 0)
    {
        fprintf(file, "%s %d %d %d\n", data[a].country, data[a].gold, data[a].silver, data[a].bronze);
        a++;
    }

    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}

int load_file(struct Olympia* data, char* filename, int i)
{
    int a = 0;

    FILE* file = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (!file)
    {
        printf("Error opening file! Try again");
    }

    struct Olympia* arr = malloc(sizeof(Olympia));

    while (fscanf(file, "%s %d %d %d", data[a].country, data[a].gold, data[a].silver, data[a].bronze))
    {
        i++;
        a++;
        arr = realloc(arr, sizeof(Olympia) * (i + 2));
    }
    arr[a].country[0] = 0;
    fclose(file);
    return arr;
}
```

And the main function

```
int main(void)
{
    char command;
    int gold = 0;
    int silver = 0;
    int bronze = 0;
    int i = 0;

    char* line = (char*)malloc((100) * sizeof(char)); //allocating memory for one stdin line
    char* countryname = (char*)malloc(20 * sizeof(char)); // allocating memory for country name
    char* filename = (char*)malloc(100 * sizeof(char));
    struct Olympia* countrydata = malloc(sizeof(struct Olympia) * 1); //allocating memory for structure

    line = fgets(line, 100, stdin);

    while(1)
    {
        sscanf(line, "%c %s %d %d %d", &command, countryname, &gold, &silver, &bronze);

        switch (command)
        {
            case 'A':

                i = add_country(countrydata, countryname, i);
                countrydata = realloc(countrydata, sizeof(struct Olympia) * (i + 1));
                break;

            case 'M':

                update_medals(countrydata, countryname, gold, silver, bronze, i);
                break;

            case 'L':

                print_data(countrydata, i);
                break;

            case 'W':

                save_file(countrydata, filename, i);
                break;

            case 'O':

                i = load_file(countrydata,filename, i);
                break;

            case 'Q':

                free(line);
                free(countryname);
                free(countrydata);
                return(EXIT_SUCCESS);
        }

        line = fgets(line, 100, stdin);

        if (line == NULL)
        {
            free(line);
            free(countryname);
            free(countrydata);
            return(EXIT_SUCCESS);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: I have a problem to make a text file named by user that contains the structure and then download it back to stdout and I don't know how to fix my functions to do this correctly

Comment: Take a debugger and step through the code.

Comment: L0KiZ:   Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You call `save_file(countrydata, filename, i);` without having set `filename`. Change to `save_file(countrydata, line, i);` since for whatever reason you expect the command character `W` to precede the name.

Then in `save_file()` the condition in `while (data[a].country[0] != 0)` is unusable, since the data element after the last one is not initialized. Use `while (a < i)` instead.